# Script for ; Select Same fill color and object group for all colors separately

Tags: adobe-illustrator, script

In Illustrator 2019 CMD+G does not work to select all the colors.

I need to select all the separate colors and make them groups.

Does anyone have a script that would do this please?

Comment: Are you using a Mac? I am not sure but you can follow the [shortcut list](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/default-keyboard-shortcuts.html) provided by adobe illustrator itself when working with groups.

Comment: yes working with MacBook

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking... cmd+g is the shortcut for *group* it has *nothing* to do with "colors". `Select > Same > Fill & Stroke` will select objects of the same color as a selected object. Please clarify the question. No one here knows what you are trying to accomplish or why.

Comment: very sorry. I have many designs which have many colours to change so my job is to change the colours.

Comment: I am using select same fill and then i am using object group. This takes a long time as i have so many designs with so many colours - i was hoping to find something to make this job quicker but it doesn't look like there is a way on MacBook.

Comment: @NehaSharma it is unlikely that grouping will help here. Since grouping changes the stacking order. So while yes it makes changing the color easy. IT also  has high chance of making the artwork broken. Use *Edit -> Edit colors -> Recolor artwork* or adjust instead. Or collect the colors as global swatches.

Comment: @joojaa is correct. For my money, global swatches may be easiest. You can change the *actual* swatch and all objects colored with that swatch change as well. One place to edit. But, of course, you need to have *all* objects filled with a *global* swatch first.

Comment: If you can verify this is what you need then a better solution may be built.